# VIM - Map a local folder to a remote folder

Tags: vim, ssh, sftp, synchronize, sshfs

I am used to Sublime's SFTP plugin - It lets you map a local folder to a remote folder. Which mean that the file you are working on is automatically updates in the remote server when you hit the save button. This is a must-have when I work on dev websites as I can run Grunt tasks on my local folder to get my css and my js minified,…

However I recently gave a try to the VIM editor which is pretty cool and I found this plugin [vim-sync](https://github.com/eshion/vim-sync/) that looks similar but I couldn't get it work.
I did a lot of research and I ended up using [SSHFS](http://osxfuse.github.io/) but it's actually way too slow especially when I SSHFS through multiple connections.

I am not particularly looking for a VIM plugin. I found great tools like [rsync](http://troy.jdmz.net/rsync/index.html) but it's a bit of a pain as I need to enter the command line and the server password every time I want to sync.

You have to know that I do not have permissions on servers(so I can't use tool like [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) nor create a SSH key for rsync), I sometimes need to SSH via a specific port and I sometimes need to use a SSH key.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I apologise for any mistakes in my english.

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the people encountering the same issue I recommend you to have a look at the [vim-hsftp](https://github.com/hesselbom/vim-hsftp) plugin. I didn't try it when I found it because I thought it wouldn't work with SSH key but you simply need to write the path to it instead of the password and you are good to go. Easy as pie, it's exactly what I was looking for.

Well done to the guy who built this plugin.

Comment: does anyone get "/bin/bash: expect: command not found shell returned 127" when trying to do upload with <leader> hsu ?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look whether the *netrw* plugin that ships with Vim already fulfills your needs.

Just specify remote files like this:

```
:edit scp://[user@]host/path
```

It should work transparently. For details (such as how to set up users and passwords), see `:help netrw`.

Comment: Hi Ingo! Thank you for your quick answer. I heard of netrw when I searched for a solution. I gave it a quick try but it's not exactly what I am looking for as it won't let me run Grunt. It simply lets me open the file I want but do no let me synchronise a local folder, am I correct?

Comment: Correct, this is just for remotely editing single files. Remember, Vim is not an IDE, so don't expect features unrelated to the core text editing.

Comment: It makes sense. However I don't think Sublime Text is an IDE neither and I thought it would exist similar plugins on VIM. Do you have any thoughts of tools or softwares that might do the job?

Comment: I can only think of SSHFS.